# Sybase SQL: How to extract numbers from varchar-values?

Tags: sql, sybase

I have a bunch of values (varchars) that consist partly of letters (whereby number of letters >= 0) and partly of numbers.

For example:

```
abc-123
defjke12345 
987654
```

Is there a function in sybase sql that extracts the part of the value that consists of numbers?

Continuing with the given examples,

```
abc-123          should become 123
defjke12345      should become 12345 
987654           should stay   987654
```

How can I achieve this in sybase sql (procedural language)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out with the substring and pattern index:

```
DECLARE @yourfield VARCHAR(100)
SELECT  @yourfield ='defjke12345'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@yourfield , PATINDEX('%[^0-9][0-9]%', @yourfield ) + 1, 
PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', @yourfield ) - PATINDEX('%[^0-9][0-9]%', @yourfield ))
```